# Changing a light switch with 9 wires , just a normal 1way

Tags: wiring

I am trying to change a light switch from a dimmable to a normal 1 way light switch. There are 3 red 3 black and 3 earth's. One red black and earth are producing current the others are not. Can someone tell me where the wires should go?

[image]

[image]

Comment: They go in the same labelled terminals as the switch you just removed. Hope you took pictures... [otherwise you have to start testing where each cable goes]

Comment: I stupidly didn't take photos

Comment: The second picture makes me considerably more wary of saying anything about the first picture. What country is this?

Comment: I am in the uk does it look different from what you would expect

Comment: I wouldn't expect that second photo at all, but then I'm not a qualified sparky, so I'll leave potential explanations for wiring it like that to those who are.

Comment: Has any other light fixture or outlet stopped working? I'm betting at least one set is a continuation of the "hot" feed.  But at this point you need to call in a licensed electrician.

Comment: Hey thanks everyone yeah just the other bedroom has stopped. I will call in an electrician not the simple swap light switch I'm use to

Answer (score 2):

It looks like lighting wiring, but the variety where the power and onward lines come into the switch, with only a spur to the lamp.

All the earths always go together, to each other and also to anything else in the box that has an earth terminal, including switches, receptacles or the box itself.  "That was easy", push them into the back of the box and forget them.

Black is "old school colors" neutral, and since we don't have a switch leg we can be confident all black wires are actually neutral.

The cable that has power: is certainly the line coming in from the supply. (i.e. either straight from the consumer unit/service panel, or another switch or lamp).  That will be "always-live".

Another cable carries "always-live" power onward to serve other switches or lamps in a similar way.

The third cable goes to the lamp.  Its neutral *must* be always connected.  Its live (red) wire is connected to "live" when you want the lamp to be lit.  That is the role of the switch, at the risk of stating the obvious.

So the two "always-live" red wires (supply, and onward to other switches/lamps) need to go together.  (i.e. in the same lug of the switch, if the switch is rated/approved for 2 wires per lug).  "Lamp" goes on the other switch lug.

Should you experiement? Generally no, as many combinations will seem to work but set the stage to kill you later.  But in this situation, once earths and neutrals are properly connected, experimenting with arrangements of "live" on a switch is harmless. Well, assuming you turn the circuit breaker off before touching or arranging wires!

The final arrangement will be with supply and "onward" connected to one switch lug, and lamp to the other switch lug.

Comment: Hi again , can I ask once you find where the red wires go. Light red wire into L1 , and supply and outward red into common. How.do you connect the 3 black neutral wires.  I know these were connected previously with a wire strip but I read two wires shouldn't go into the same whole.of a wire stripe so what's the best thing to use to connect two wires together I.e. the neutral supply and neutral light wire , then the supply out wire or can all 3 go together

Comment: USA has a "1 neutral per hole" rule for panels (consumer units), but it does not apply to the UK.  Depends on the wire strip, you have to check the labeling and instructions for them. I believe in this setup, all neutral wires need to end up connected to each other.